# Clicks on anchors and carousel controls are closing the modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a modal with carousel in it that appears on click of a picture thumbnail. The problem is that whenever I click the arrows used for navigating between the pictures the modal closes. The images are loaded dynamically from the database, that's why the `<div class="carousel-inner">` is empty

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control-prev left" href="#modal-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next right" href="#modal-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
    })

   /* activate the carousel */
   $("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

   /* change modal title when slide changes */
   $("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
        $(".modal-title")
        .html($(this)
        .find(".active img")
        .attr("title"));
   });

   /* when clicking a thumbnail */
   $(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title");
    content.empty();  
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;  
     var repo = $("#img-repo .carousel-item");
     var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
     var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
  });

});
```

Some days ago it worked like a charm and don't know what did I do to break it.

Thanks

Comment: create a working fiddle

Comment: I can't create a working fiddle because the whole thing doesn't work. Go to [link](http://mebelbox.bg) and click the second item in the navigation menu. You'll see it there.

Comment: you said that the modal working but when you click the arrow the modal disappear, then it's working but it has an issue which is difficult to be resolved unless you post a working snippet.

Comment: Check the link that I provided.

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at gallery?page=1&furnitureType=1:167_ check the error from console and try solving it maybe it will solve your problem

Comment: The problem is not there. I had already resolved that locally. Check it again. I resolved it in the production app too.

Comment: problem solved check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you forget `.modal-content` which is the only and the direct child of `.modal-dialog`, see the sample from [The Official Bootstrap Site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)

Your code must be like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content"><!-- .modal-content class added -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev left" href="#modal-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next right" href="#modal-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You already have a direct `div` child under `modal-dialog` but without any class.

Add `class="modal-content"` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention! Such a simple and stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your content is inside an element which listens to click events and closes the modal. To help you understand the problem, I will explain this in simple terms:

Let's suppose you have an X and an Y tag. Y tag is the descendant of X, or, structurally, it is inside X. When you click on Y, the click event will occur and it will trigger a click event on its parent tag, the second click (this time on the parent of Y) will be handled and a click will be triggered on the parent of a parent (of Y) and so on, so all the ancestors of Y will be clicked if Y is clicked. This is the default behavior.

Your problem is that clicking on an anchor will eventually trigger a click on the element which, when clicked should close the modal. The solution is to add a click event to the children of the element which is responsible of fading the model and make sure you stop propagating the click event to higher structural elements, by calling

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. It doesn't matter where I click, the modal closes. Even on the picture.

Comment: @DanielGeorgiev where did you put e.stopPropagation(); ?